# Running a command line .net application on boot, as a user, without needing login

Tags: login, startup, reboot, auto-login, dotnet

I have a dotnet console application that when executed will run a loop and await a keypress. On certain keypresses it will perform an action (via api calls etc..)

I have a raspberry pi running ubuntu server 22.10 (64 bit) on the pi.

I want to run a command like this:

```
dotnet /home/myuser/src/prototypes/devops-control/Client/bin/Debug/net6.0/devops-control.dll "loop"
```

when the pi boots up so that I can use a simple macro pad as a keyboard, and send the command to the application.

The application is basically

```
if arg[0] == 'loop' 
{
    while(true)
    {
        var key = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
        PerformAction(key)
    }
}
```

I have dotnet installed, and setup in the path of my user (if I ssh in and run the command everything works as expected)

But I would just like this to happen when I boot the pi up so I can leave it headless with just a macro pad plugged in.

Ideally it would simply boot up, auto login as the user without me putting in a password, and then run the command which would run the application waiting for keypresses. Meaning I can ssh into the pi and pull new version of the code etc.. and just have it all in one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run the process as a systemd service.

It's a bit of a long process and here is one [nice article that explains the steps](https://abhinand05.medium.com/run-any-executable-as-systemd-service-in-linux-21298674f66f) (and provides some background).

Here's another explanation that may help [from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22336075/linux-process-into-a-service).

And, finally, one that shows how to [set up a .NET app to run that way](https://swimburger.net/blog/dotnet/how-to-run-a-dotnet-core-console-app-as-a-service-using-systemd-on-linux).

And, here is a great resource [from DigitalOcean that shows how to manage services](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units).

Comment: You are a star. Thanks!

Comment: This does sort of answer my question, so I have marked it as such. @raddevus thanks for the info. Alas, these "background workers" don't capture keyboard input via Console.Read as I had hoped (which makes sense, as they run in the background without a console window open) Do you know what would be the best way to capture input from a systemd service?